# how to detect when user typing in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I want to make a program like Co-Writer. 
its a word prediction program that's helps user when the user typing in anywhere(notepad,browser,msword,etc) the program will popup and give the user suggestion of word.

what I don't understand is how to make the program popup when the user typing. 
can anyone giving me some advice or suggestion?

I don't know what programming language is the best for this. but now I still thinking about doing this in Visual Basic.

Comment: You need to at least provide what you have tried so far, we do not write code for you on this site.

Comment: What platform: wpf? winforms? windows store? other?

Comment: @Sanpopo no, i didnt mean to you write all the coding for me. I already make a couple programs with vb. I just didnt know how to make a background proccess in vb. I just need a name for it

Answer (score 0):

To do that effectively, you will have to use the WinAPI. If this is your first project, that may be too confusing. As far as the language itself, honestly it doesn't matter as much as you think it does. Design your project. Get pen and paper and figure out exactly what it is you want, not just a general idea. Then write the internal part of the program. Write the code that gets which keys are being pressed and see if you can get it to give suggestions. Then you can move on to getting it to follow you around in other applications. I would start with something simpler if this is your first project.

We also have a harder time helping you if you don't post your code.

Comment: No, this isn't my first project, i already made couple program with vb. I just want to know how to make it work with other programs. Is it possible in VB ? What is  the name of it? So i can search in google and figure out. Is WinApi for c++?

Comment: The problem lies in one of the fundamental ideas of programming. Getting programs to talk to each other usually requires both programs to be aware and communicate intentionally. What you're suggesting would need to work for all programs. That means that you need to use WinAPI to communicate and detect when a key is pressed.

A quick Google search yields this particular methodology.

http://tech.reboot.pro/showthread.php?tid=3342